# How to get rid of duplicates in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I am new to prolog and I have a hierarchical database that lists employees and their supervisors:

```
employee(employee1, employee4).
employee(employee2, employee4).
employee(employee3, employee4).
employee(employee4, employee8).
employee(employee5, employee7).
employee(employee6, employee7).
employee(employee7, employee8).
employee(employee8, employee9).
employee(employee9, employee10).
```

I want to make a predicate called coworker(A, B) that lists all the coworkers a certain employee has, includng his/her superiors.

```
coworker(Who, employee1).
Who = employee2 ?;
Who = employee3 ?;
Who = employee4 ?;
Who = employee5 ?;
Who = employee6 ?;
Who = employee7 ?;
Who = employee8 ?;
Who = employee9 ?;
Who = employee10 ?;
```

My code so far is this:

```
supervisor(A,B):-employee(B,A).

boss(A,B):-supervisor(A,B).
boss(A,B):-supervisor(A,C),boss(C,B).

coworker(A,B):-boss(C,A),boss(C,B).
coworker(A,B):-employee(A,B).
coworker(A,B):-supervisor(A,B).
coworker(A,B):-boss(X,Y).
```

However, I'm having difficulty completely getting rid of every possible duplicate of a coworker. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Try tracing with `trace.` before running your query. Odds are good it's something simple but non-obvious, like `boss(C,A), boss(C,B), B \= A.` that you're missing.

Comment: in SWI-Prolog, see library([solution_sequences](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=solutionsequences))